# Can non runnable task be passed to ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I want to update a legacy piece of code where user defined threadpool is used. I want to use java ThreadPoolExecutor, but the problem is the request that are being send to threadpool is not Runnable. Is there any way I can use ThreadPoolExecutor with the existing request(which is not Runnable).

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could write an adapter class ([Design pattern: Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)) implementing `Runnable` which wraps instances of your class and delegates from the `run` method to your objects equivalent.

Example:

```
class MyClass {
    public void doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}

class MyClassThreadPoolAdapter implements Runnable {
    private MyClass myClass;

    public MyClassThreadPoolAdapter(MyClass myClass) {
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }

    public void run() {
        this.myClass.doSomething();
    }
}
```